# Fastest way to list all edges that form a cycle in a graph if one edge that forms the cycle is known

Tags: algorithm, graph

I've been going through algorithms for finding edges that form a cycle in an undirected graph(in particular: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-undirected-graph/). What I'm asking though is: are there any fast approaches to finding such a cycle if one edge is already known?(only one such cycle) What I thought of is applying the isCyclicUtil only on the two vertices that form the edge(or maybe only one) and using the visited array to check for the edges that form it. Is there any faster way however of solving this. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: If you have an edge between A and B, and you know it forms a part of a cycle, remove it and find a path between A and B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since A and B are bi-connected vertices, you could remove the edge between them and run DFS / BFS to find a path between them. This path is indeed a cycle in the original graph (the one with the removed edge).